# Is there an easy way to view the raw database content in Spring / JPA?

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa

Is it possible to view the actual database table content in a Spring application? This can either be the typical SQL output printed to System.out:

[image]

Or any other type of interactive table view.

This would be used in the context of spring unit tests that use an in-memory database - so there is no separate SQL-type prompt that can be used (unless there's an easy way to connect this to the in-memory database).

Preferably this is without writing different code for each entity class / repository. The main purpose is to be able to quickly see / debug what is being added to the database tables when testing the application (next to writing the actual test cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the H2 in-memory database, you can use the H2 console to access the database.

You will need the following properties:

- `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` (the value of this property will need to be filled in in the H2 console login screen as URL)
- `spring.h2.console.enabled=true`

And when unit testing, will need to add `webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT` to your `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the Console for Hibernate Tools, available at https://hibernate.org/tools/

Comment: Is this only in combination with JBoss Tools or can you use it outside of JBoss? I don't immediately find a separate plugin with only the Hibernate Tools.

Comment: Everything can be isolated since it's Java, how much work will that require will depend. Yet, if you're looking for such a specific tool, I'd suggest, just be pragmatic and use it as it comes.